# WebChromeClient onJsAlert receives undefined message

Tags: javascript, android

I have an android webview with a WebChromeClient installed on it.
Upon a certain action in the webpage, I create a javascript alert with a message, which is passed back to the onJsAlert method.

Then, based on the message I open another activity.
This works good on Android >= 4 but does not work on Android 2.3.

On Android 2.3 the onJsAlert method also gets called, but the passed message parameter is undefined for some reason. Any idea why this might happen, will be really appreciated!

Comment: i too had done this...but my code works good on 2.3 too..do you get any error?if yes can you pls provide your error log

Comment: No unfortunately, there is no error. The only related logs are: ```webview(9457):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE```, ```I/Web Console(9457): slideshow: at undefined:1```, ```D/DEBUG(9457): MESSAGE OF JS IS: undefined``` and the last two are from me

Comment: ok should i post my code here for you to match with yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code i used

```
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.demo);

    try {
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyJavaScriptChromeClient());

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/texthtml.html");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class MyJavaScriptChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,
            final JsResult result) {
        // handle Alert event, here we are showing AlertDialog


        new AlertDialog.Builder(WebActivity.this)
                .setTitle("JavaScript Alert !")
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                        new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // do your stuff
                                result.confirm();
                            }
                        }).setCancelable(false).create().show();
        return true;
    }

}
```

and this my html file

```
<html>
```

```
<div onclick="alert('hello')"> Click Me !!  </div>
```

Comment: The problem was elsewhere and lied within the input to my javascript function, which then indeed did return undefined. I just assumed that the javascript function works correctly and the problem should lie within the onJsAlert Callback or somewhere else. Nonetheless, I am accepting your answer as it helped me see that this part of my code was correct and I should look elsewhere. Thanks!